# File Not Found in WebSphere 5.1

Tags: websphere

My Web.xml
...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MaintenanceModeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jc.servlet.MaintenanceModeServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MaintenanceModeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MaintenanceModeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

...

This is the fragment of the Servlet that calls my MaintenanceModeServlet….

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        MaintenanceMode m = new MaintenanceMode();
        if (m.isDowntimeFlag()) {
            System.out.println("Calling MaintenanceModeServlet....");
            MVCUtility.forwardRequest("/MaintenanceModeServlet", req, resp);
            return;     
        }
```

…..

StackTrace…
PrintStackTrace: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: File not found: /MaintenanceModeServlet at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponseContext.sendError(SRTServletResponseContext.java:174) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:686) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.SimpleFileServlet.doGet(SimpleFileServlet.java:409) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:740) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StrictServletInstance.doService(StrictServletInstance.java:110) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StrictLifecycleServlet._service(StrictLifecycleServlet.java:174) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.IdleServletState.service(StrictLifecycleServlet.java:313) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StrictLifecycleServlet.service(StrictLifecycleServlet.java:116) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.service(ServletInstance.java:283) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ValidServletReferenceState.dispatch(ValidServletReferenceState.java:42) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstanceReference.dispatch(ServletInstanceReference.java:40) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.handleWebAppDispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1018) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:529) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:208) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WebAppInvoker.doForward(WebAppInvoker.java:134) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WebAppInvoker.handleInvocationHook(WebAppInvoker.java:321) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.cache.invocation.CachedInvocation.handleInvocation(CachedInvocation.java:71) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srp.ServletRequestProcessor.dispatchByURI(ServletRequestProcessor.java:246) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.oselistener.OSEListenerDispatcher.service(OSEListener.java:334) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:56) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:652) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:448) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:937)

The error only happens when it runs from the WebSphere App Server, on the localhost there is no issue. Any idea why it cannot find the MaintenanceModeServlet when in fact it’s there?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You also have to take the applications context path into account. If you do not want to be dependent on what the context path is you can change your code to include the context path in the forward:

```
MVCUtility.forwardRequest(req.getContextPath() + "/MaintenanceModeServlet", req, resp);
```